# Read and display Proxy Server settings that are defined under Internet Options - Lan Settings with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, proxy

I want to read the proxy settings (if any defined) and display them to the user via a windows forms application.

Until now I am using code like the following:

```
WebProxy defaultProxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
if (defaultProxy != null)
{
    ProxyAddress = defaultProxy.Address.Host;
    ProxyPort = defaultProxy.Address.Port;
    ProxyDefaultCredentials = defaultProxy.UseDefaultCredentials;
    ProxyByPassLocalAddresses = defaultProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal;
    ProxyByPassAddressList = defaultProxy.BypassList;
    //...etc...
}
```

I don't want to use the proxy to proceed calling an internet resource. I just want to read those values and display them to the user on a dialog.
I have tried to use all the (kind of) related WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy, HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy(), etc. with no luck because they are all related to an upcomming web request to specified web resource. Also, those properties and methods are giving just an indication that if you try to call the "x" uri, a proxy server, may, or may not be used during that request.

Once again, I just want to show a similar form like that one under the internet settings when the poxy server setings are defined (server address, ports, bypass list, ect.).

Thats all...

Comment: "etc. with no luck because they are all related to an upcomming web request to specified web resource" I don't understand this. What exactly is your problem? Using `GetDefaultProxy()` seems fine to me.

Comment: @floele, all related WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy and HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy() are returning  either a Uri object or IWebProxy where no usable infomation of the proxy settings can be found in order to display them, (there are only private properties that can not be read directly). GetDefaultProxt() is deprecated and is going to be removed in a future updates of the .Net Framework in may be less than a year, so it must be changed to something else. One way is to create a fake web request and get the underlying proxy (if any). That solves partially the problem...